# What does this sound issue means in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, audio-player

Hi everyone I face an issue when playing sound on a Flutter App (XYLOPHONE APP, in this capture). Firstly the sound plays normally when I push each coloried  button which plays differents sounds. But after somes seconds no sound is played. Here is the capture with the error messages in the RUN panel. What does it means???

**NB: I use the audioplayers package from pub.dev**

[FLUTTER APP ISSUE CAPTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5YKZ.png)

**THIS IS THE CODE OF THE APP**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.orange,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(2);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(3);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(4);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.teal,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(5);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(6);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: null,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(7);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Try to put some relevant code here, say the lib that are you using or another information that can be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I use audioplayers package. I have given the code in the updated post.

Comment: did you try to use low latency mode?
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);

Comment: When using AudioPlayer instead of AudioCache compiler tell me there is unused import of AudioCache. All my sounds are in assets directory that's why I used AudioCache as recommended in the docs